# Finding orthogonal basis of subspace spanned by the vectors

Tags: vectors, orthogonality, gram-schmidt

v1 = (2,3,t), v2 = (t,t<sup>2</sup>, t<sup>2</sup>). For each t when v1 and v2 are not orthogonal, find an orthogonal basis of the subspace spanned by v1 and v2.

In this case does finding an orthogonal basis of the subspace spanned by v1 and v2 mean the same as transforming the vectors into an orthogonal basis {v1,v2}?

Comment: Yes, apply Gram-Schmidt on $v_1,v_2$.

Comment: @Ch. Siva Ram Kishore:  The cross product of two vectors is perpendicular to both so does not lie in then space spanned by them.